# sigaction System Call

Tags: c, linux, macros, posix, signals

I was looking at the man page of sigaction, and I ended up looking at the following line.

```
sigaction(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE
```

What do _POSIX_X_SOURCE, _X_OPEN_SOURCE, _POSIX_SOURCE mean? What to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

These are **feature test macros**. Their purpose is to allow your program to inform the system header files which standards you want it to attempt to conform to, and what extensions you want available.

Without any feature test macros defined, implementations vary a lot in what macros, functions, and type definitions they make visible in their headers. A common practice is to make *everything* visible by default, which is a problem because "everything" is not very specific, and it's very possible that symbol names used in your program might clash with some of the extensions. Even if they don't clash now, there's no way to know if they will in the future. So the standards (like ISO C and POSIX) put strict requirements on the implementation that it not pollute the applications namespace with names not explicitly defined or reserved in the standards. When you use a feature test macro to request a particular standard, you're asking the implementation to ensure that (1) it provides everything defined in this standard, (2) it doesn't pollute your application's namespace by providing anything not defined in that standard.

A correct program should always explicitly use the right feature test macros for the standard(s) it's written to. The easiest way to do this is putting the right `-D` argument on the compiler command line (`CFLAGS`). Adding the `#define` as the first line in each source file also works. Be aware if you do it in source files though:

1. The feature test macros must be defined at the top **before any system header is included**.
2. It's usually a bad idea to use different feature test macros in different translation units.

As an aside, it's not exactly the same as the other feature test macros, but all modern programs should define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` when built on Linux/glibc to request that `off_t` be 64-bit for large file support.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a man for Feature macros: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html

They will turn on or off some level of standard support in the headers.

E.g. _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 means that POSIX.2-1992 or later should be supported; _X_OPEN_SOURCE means POSIX.1,    POSIX.2, and XPG4 are enabled; and for greater values of macro (>=500; >=600; >=700) it will also turn on some variants of SUSv2 v3 or v4 (UNIX 98; 03 or  POSIX.1-2008+XSI). And _POSIX_SOURCE is an obsolete way to define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE = 1

Answer (score 1):

They're the things you have to `#define` to get the prototype, and are known as [feature test macros](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html).

For example, the following code will susscessfully define the prototype for `sigaction`:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <signal.h>
```

Including `signal.h` *without* that `#define` (or the others) will not define the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

It is a **[Feature test macro.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html)**

> Symbols called "feature test macros" are used to control the visibility of symbols that might be included in a header. Implementations, future versions of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, and other standards may define additional feature test macros.